# Streaming encrypted copyright content (audio/video) with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, audio-streaming, drm

Is possible to stream encrypted content (DRM) using only Javascript and HTML5 audio and video tags, leaving behind and not using the SWF approach?

Comment: Hi Joao! :) You might want to read about EME http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  If you just need transport encryption, there's HTTPS.  If you need DRM, that's a bit different.  If you need to be compatible with existing encrypted media. that's also a different scenario.

Comment: Hi Brad! I need DRM (I forgot to mention). EME could be a good option but only the most recent versions of some browsers support it

Comment: EME seems to be the only option to avoid using Flash, Silverlight. But someone else with experience on the subject might have other opinions

Comment: The question is rather vague - what exactly are you looking for? The quick answer is "yes" but this question could really be improved a lot if you describe what you have already tried and what your overall goals and wishes are with regard to any answer.

Comment: Oi João! Have you been working more on this? looking for the same thing and thought about asking :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes - you can playback encrypted content with certain browsers just using HTML5.

Let's look at the entire workflow.

On the server side: you have to encrypt your content and provide a license server.

for example:

- Microsoft PlayReady License Servers or
- [Media Source Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Source_Extensions)

On the client side: you need a browser that supports encrypted media extensions (EME).

- Chrome 34+
- IE 11+ on Windows 8+
- Safari 8+ on Mac OS

Netflix started working on it two years ago: http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/04/html5-video-at-netflix.html
and supports it now on a variety of browsers and platforms.

Comment: Firefox should support it now, too, they should not?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use Encrypted Media extension for it:

here is a link from w3c:

https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/

more explanation with programmatic sample here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/